# Cannot launch node of type with joystick tutorial

Tags: ros, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the tutorial "joy/Tutorials/Writing/TeleopNode. I am running Ubuntu 11.10 with fuerte.  I am trying to use a Logtech Rumble Pad joystick.  Here is a copy of my launch file:

```
<launch>

 <!-- Turtlesim Node-->
  <node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" name="sim"/>


 <!-- joy node -->
  <node respawn="true" pkg="joy"
        type="joy" name="turtle_joy" >
   <param name="dev" type="string" value="/dev/input/js1" />
   <param name="deadzone" value="0.12" />
 </node>

<!-- Axes -->
 <param name="axis_linear" value="1" type="int"/>
 <param name="axis_angular" value="0" type="int"/>
 <param name="scale_linear" value="2" type="double"/>
 <param name="scale_angular" value="2" type="double"/>

 <node pkg="turtle_teleop" type="turtle_teleop_joy" name="teleop"/>
```

I am getting an error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [turtle_teleop/turtle_teleop_joy]: turtle_teleop
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/brent/ros_workspace
ROS path [2]=/home/brent/ros
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
```

Turtlesim does come up, but I am not getting any movement with my joystick.  I do get a reading from echo joy.

Any help would be appreciated,

Morpheus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48505/cannot-launch-node-of-type-with-joystick-tutorial/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-11-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2012-11-17**:
Here is my launch file:   1 
2
3  
4   
5
6
7  
8   <node respawn="true" pkg="joy"
9         type="joy" name="turtle_joy" >
10     <param name="dev" type="string" value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking more carefully at the tutorial I noticed last line after the launch file, "Since we built everything in package learning_joy, you may need to change the package in the last line from turtle_teleop to learning_joy." I made the change to my launch file, and everything works fine.

Thanks for your help,
Morpheus

---

Originally posted by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) with karma: 111 on 2012-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please **edit** your question and provide the complete launch file, correctly formatted (mark the code and press Ctrl-k). Did you maybe copy-paste the line numbers?

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2012-11-19**:
Deleting line numbers.  I am getting, ERROR: cannot launch node of type [turtle_teleop/turtle_teleop_joy]: turtle_teleop
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/brent/ros_workspace
ROS path [2]=/home/brent/ros
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-19**:
As I said before, please **edit** your question. Reading error messages or code in comments is really hard. As your error clearly says, you are missing the node you are trying to launch. Did you install it?

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2012-11-22**:
I hope that I have edited my question a little better.